# ClassNotFoundException with Netbeans and H2 Database

Tags: database, netbeans, classpath, database-connection, h2

So I followed the tutorial on the H2 Documentation page and used the "Connecting to a Database using JDBC" method of connecting to the database. I First added the h2-*.jar file to the Lib Folder (through Netbeans) and used the following to make the connection to my database I previously created.

```
 Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
 connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/" + DatabaseName);
```

This turned out to work in the IDE environment, however when I attempted to run the application directly from the jar executable I get the following error:

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.h2.Driver ...
```

this error occurs at the Class.forName() class loader. So I did a little looking around and found that this was a prominent problem. One solution people use was to extract the class Loader from the current Thread as so:

```
 Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
 ClassLoader cl = t.getContextClassLoader();
 cl.getClass().getClassLoader();
 Class toRun = cl.loadClass("org.h2.Driver");
```

Unfortunately this seems to still result in the same error, so i'm wondering what i'm doing wrong. Should I be doing something to make sure the Driver is in the class path? I have no I idea how if that's the case.

Thanks!

Comment: "One solution people use was to extract the class Loader from the current Thread" - where did you find that? It not related to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [add the `h2-*.jar` file to the classpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29#Adding_all_JAR_files_in_a_directory) when running the application, for example using

```
java -cp h2*.jar -jar yourApp.jar
```

Comment: should't adding it to the Libraries folder through the IDE do that? I use other libraries and all I had to do was add to the libraries and I can freely refer to the specific package using class.getResources("package.name")

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what 'adding to the Libraries folder of the IDE' means.

Comment: You wrote "when I attempted to run the application directly from the jar executable". That means outside Netbeans, right? If yes, then the Netbeans config might not help at all.